# How to monitor Uniform Distributed Queues on Weblogic 12

Tags: java, oracle, jms, weblogic12c

I need to monitor a Uniform Distributed Queue configured on WebLogic Server: 12.1.3.0.0.
Looking at the Oracle docs seems that it's possible monitor statistics on uniform distributed queue resources in JMS modules through "JMSDestinationRuntimeMBean" class.

Here the link:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jms_admin/manage_msg.html#wp1125870

Below my code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>();
h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "weblogic123");         

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(h);

Destination queue = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jms/MyQueue");    

JMSDestinationRuntimeMBean destMBean = JMSRuntimeHelper.getJMSDestinationRuntimeMBean(ctx, queue);

System.out.println("count: " + destMBean.getMessagesCurrentCount());
```

On execution I got this exception on `getJMSDestinationRuntimeMBean`method:

`weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: JMS Destination runtime mbean not found`

I've tryed to execute that code on a simple Queue (not distributed) and it works.

Comment: I found two ways to do that. You can find more details [here](http://www.madbit.org/blog/programming/1385/how-to-monitor-jms-queues-on-weblogic-in-java/#sthash.cq8Abxkt.dpbs) and [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=100)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Google `weblogic jmx jms` and there are lots of examples